# Function does not print the right output

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter

I have written a small app with checkboxes, so when I mark one or both of them it should print a specific variable, though, the problem lays here, when I mark both of the checkboxes, I don't get the output I want.

```
from tkinter import *
class STproject():

    def __init__(self,app):

        self.CheckVar1 =IntVar()
        self.CheckVar2 =IntVar()

        self.button=Button(app,text='PRINT',command=lambda:self.functionality())
        self.button.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.Lidbox=Checkbutton(app,variable=self.CheckVar1,onvalue=1,
                           offvalue=0)
        self.Lidbox.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.Seperatorbox=Checkbutton(app,variable=self.CheckVar2,onvalue=1,
                           offvalue=0)
        self.Seperatorbox.grid(row=1,column=1)

    def functionality(self):
        if self.CheckVar1.get():
            print('first')
        elif self.CheckVar2.get():
            print('2nd part')
        elif self.CheckVar1.get() and self.CheckVar2.get():
            print('3rd part')
        else:
            print('4th part')

root=Tk()
root.title('SteelBox Inc. Calculator')
application=STproject(root) #2
root.mainloop() #3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of your checkboxes are checked, the first `if` will be evaluated to `True`, since `self.CheckVar1` is indeed checked. Then, the other `elif` statements won't be evaluated.

Change your code to:

```
def functionality(self):
    if self.CheckVar1.get() and self.CheckVar2.get():
        print('3rd part')
    elif self.CheckVar1.get():
        print('first')
    elif self.CheckVar2.get():
        print('2nd part')
    else:
        print('4th part')
```